# NFC : APDU and SNEP length limitation

Tags: nfc, apdu, acr122, large-data

I'm working on a project in order to exchange large data from PC to Android device throught NFC. I'm using ACR122.

The following is a general exemple of data sent :

```
// ADPU
FF FF 00 00 00 nn   // CLA, INS, P1, P2, Le, Lc
D4 40               // TFI, PD0
01                  // (Mi), Target

// LLCP
13 20               // DSAP, PTYPE, SSAP
00                  // Sequence
D4 40               // TFI, PD0

// SNEP
10 02               // Protocol Version, Action
nn nn nn nn         // Total SNEP Length

// NDEF Header
A2                  // First byte (MB = 1, ME = 0, Cf = 1, SR = 0, Il, TNF)
22                  // Type length
mm mm mm mm         // Payload length

// NDEF Content
61.....65           // Type (34 bytes in that case)
01.....01           // Payload (mm mm mm mm bytes)
```

Here, I send a Record (not short record).So the NDEF header allows to enter a 4 bytes payload length.
Finaly, my question is how could we send a such large payload regarding the 1 byte APDU Lc ?
If this limitation is only due to the pn532 chip or PS/SC, what alternative hardware would you suggest ?

Thank you for any clarification

**EDIT :**
I found what I was looking for here :
[Sending Extended APDU to Javacard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240558/sending-extended-apdu-to-javacard)
It's a hardware problem, PN532 don't support Extended APDU.

Comment: You can't split the data into chunks? just out of curiosity, how large it is?

Comment: Splitting in chunk imply specifying the Sequence Number (LLCP). The sequence number can't exced 16 (4 bits). 16 sequences of ~250bytes is very far from the possible FF FF FF FF value of the SNEP payload length. I just experiment the NFC, but I try to send about 100 kb.

Comment: I may just confuse you. but 100 k(bytes) sound like a huge number for what these tags can usually handle. so if I understand correctly, you don't have enough memory space for your requirements on the card? in that case your problem is the card, not the supporting hardware.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the problem, I'm talking about sending data from PC to Android device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've already found out the ACR122 does not support extended APDU due to a limitation of the PN532 chip.

However, there is no need to pack the entire SNEP transfer into a single APDU. You can split the payload into multiple smaller frames and send them one after another. It's only important that the NDEF header gets transmitted as a whole in the first frame.

Comment: You mean splitting in chunk records ? As I understand the chunk record procedure, I need to specify the Sequence Number N(s), R(s) for each command sent, is that right ? But the sequence number is a 4 bits field, so it can't exceed 16 (decimal). Sending 16 sequences of ~250 bytes is not enought for what I want to do.

Comment: @Inset07, Don't worry, if you would reach frame 16 just wrap around and continue with frame number zero.

Comment: @Inset07 to be honest it doesn't make much sense that you have to specify  frame-numbers by yourself. The reader should keep track of them. It's part of the guaranteed delivery protocol.

Comment: For some reason, the data exchange procedure succeed only if I specify the sequence number (N(s)). But your are right : "if you reach frame 16 just wrap around and continue with frame number zero" works !  Thanks !